# Forwarding log of a specific cPanel user from rsyslog.conf to an IP address using TCP

Tags: linux, log-files, rsyslog

Server is on CloudLinux, cPanel, LiteSpeed, imunify and CSF as firewall. i have multiple domains hosted on my server. I only want to forward one user (all) logs to an specific IP address.

Using this code

```
*.*@@<ip-address>:514
```

it forward all logs to IP

then i created a file niftlog.conf and included it in rsyslog.conf

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/niftlog.conf
```

In niftlog.conf file i tried following codes

```
if $syslogtag contains 'cpanelUserName' then @@<ip-address>:514
#if $programname == 'cpsrvd' and $syslogtag contains 'cpanelUserName' then @<ip-address>:514
#if $programname == 'cpdavd' and $syslogtag contains 'cpanelUserName' then @<ip-address><ip-address>:514
if $programname == 'exim' then @<ip-address>:514
#if $programname == 'pure-ftpd' and $syslogtag contains 'cpanelUserName' then @<ip-address>:514
if $programname == 'httpd' then @@<ip-address>:514
```

I tried all codes above but logs are not forwarding to specific IP address. Any help would be highly appreciated